# hide a form field based on value of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following html which has a form.Based on value of "ccType" ie if(ccType=='maestro')
the field with id="cvv",ie the cvv field and its label should be hidden.Im new to javascript,and I dont know how to make this work.

```
<body>


    <div id="credit-card">
        <header>
                       <span class="title" style="background-image: url('images/fethrpowered.png')"><strong>This is a secure 128-bit SSL Encrypted payment.You're safe !</strong></span>
            <a><span class="close"><img src="images/lock.png"/></span></a>



        </header>
        <section style="margin-left:60px">

     <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radios" value="radio1" checked>
   <label for="radio1">Credit Card</label>

<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radios" value="radio2">
   <label for="radio2">Debit Card</label>

    <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radios"value="radio3">
   <label for="radio3">Internet Banking</label>
    </section>
        <section id="content">


            <form method="post" action='./php/TokenProcess.php'  id="cardpayment">
<input id="txtEncryptionKey" name="txtEncryptionKey" class="tokenex_encryptionkey"
        type="hidden" value="MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA8gGPMwBRPuVyJReZGIkW
H/+Bf5pnpDN1bSR2cLYLXVT8CaSnTw74qeboSnktgYCi1D9R3Bj2fYzTIwGGZb8K
inLdxwbqZmHwrE9cFhCaHbG/E0PbqQGhXP2vbniZTT4M0i0Cbi7ES3Bw5zqNbIZZ
nX041QEpxLvIyWPKZCX+fBogNMhWfCF779aclChjHkwZMsufThVWE9xklWGxXiyt
x5aL4I5JPxq0I7cAkZGGs4aF/GxWwPaq7R3wPikJQ0YHnCMfcURzl2Hnw/inqyMy
+JB6djTq2/BdzMAhWTh3cDWq9Xu+gEkb/QCd0n1yYIdKuDISlk/AfHdWe34IvzhV
yQIDAQAB
 " />



    <div style="float:right;">
     <input type='hidden' id='ccType' name='ccType'/>
            <ul class="cards">
            <li class="visa">Visa</li>
            <li class="visa_electron">Visa Electron</li>
            <li class="mastercard">MasterCard</li>
            <li class="maestro">Maestro</li>                   
            </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="table form-fields">                   
 <div class="row">
        <div class="label">Card Number:</div>
                        <div class="input full"><input type="text"  name="ccnumber" id="ccnumber" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="min14" class="tokenex_data" data-validation-error-msg="Enter a valid card number" placeholder="4242424242424242"/><br/></div>


</div>



                    <div class="row name">
                        <div class="label">Expires On:</div>
                        <div class="input size50">
                            <select name="expiry_month" id="expiry_month" class="styled" data-validation="required">
<option selected>Select Month</option>
<option value="01">January</option>
<option value="02">February</option>
<option value="03">March</option>
<option value="04">April</option>
<option value="05">May</option>
<option value="06">June</option>
<option value="07">July</option>
<option value="08">August</option>
<option value="09">September</option>
<option value="10">October</option>
<option value="11">November</option>
<option value="12">December</option>
                            </select>
    <select name="expiry_year" id="expiry_year" class="styled" data-validation="required">
<option selected>Select Year</option>
<option value="2012">2012</option>
<option value="2013">2013</option>
<option value="2014">2014</option>
<option value="2015">2015</option>
<option value="2016">2016</option>
<option value="2017">2017</option>
<option value="2018">2018</option>
<option value="2019">2019</option>
<option value="2020">2020</option>
<option value="2021">2021</option>
<option value="2022">2022</option>
<option value="2023">2023</option>
<option value="2024">2024</option>
<option value="2025">2025</option>
<option value="2026">2026</option>                          <option value="2027">2027</option>
<option value="2028">2028</option>
<option value="2029">2029</option>
<option value="2030">2030</option>
<option value="2031">2031</option>
<option value="2032">2032</option>
<option value="2033">2033</option>
<option value="2034">2034</option>
<option value="2035">2035</option>
<option value="2036">2036</option>
</select>   

                        </div>
                        <div class="valid"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row name">
                        <div class="label">CVV Number:</div>
                        <div class="input full"><input type="text" name="cvv" id="cvv" placeholder="123" maxlength="3" data-validation="number" data-validation-error-msg="Enter 3 digit CVV"/></div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="row name">
                        <div class="label">Amount:</div>
                        <div class="input full"><input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" placeholder="10.00" data-validation="number" data-validation-allowing="float" data-validation-error-msg="Enter an amount as 00.00" /></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                                                <div class="label">Your name:</div>
                        <div class="input full"><input type="text" name="name_on_card" id="name_on_card" data-validation="required" data-validation-error-msg="Enter Name as on card" placeholder="Enter the name as mentioned on the card"/></div>


                    </div>


                    <div class="row name">
                        <div class="label">Email:</div>
                        <div class="input full"><input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your Email ID" data-type="email" data-validation="email"data-validation-error-msg="Enter a valid e-mail"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row name">
                        <div class="label">Mobile Number:</div>
                        <div class="input full"><input type="text" name="mobileNo" id="mobileNo" maxlength="10" data-validation="number" data-validation-error-msg="Enter a valid 10 digit mobile number" placeholder="Enter mobile number" data-type="number"  /></div>
                    </div>


                    <input type="hidden" name="merchant_id">
                       <input type="hidden" name="customerReferenceNo">

                    </div>

                 <input type="hidden" name="selectedRadioValue" id="selectedRadioValue" />

                <input type="submit" name="btn_process" id="btn_process" class="tokenex_submit" style="float:right" value="Pay Now"/>
            </form>

    <form method="post" action='./php/IB.php' id="internetpayment" style="margin-top:30px">


    <div class="table form-fields">     

        <div class="row name">
                        <div class="label">Name:</div>
                        <div class="input full"><input type="text" name="name" id="Name" data-validation="required" data-validation-error-msg="Enter your name" placeholder="Enter your name"/></div>
                    </div>

        <div class="row name">
                        <div class="label">Email:</div>
                        <div class="input full"><input type="text" name="email" data-required="true" data-type="email" data-validation="email"data-validation-error-msg="Enter a valid e-mail" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email address"/></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row name">
                <div class="label">Mobile Number:</div>
                        <div class="input full"><input type="text" data-validation="number" data-required="number" maxlenth="10" name="Mobile Number" id="mobileNo" data-validation-error-msg="Enter a valid 10digit mobile number" placeholder="Enter your mobile number"/></div>


                    </div>
                    <div class="row name">
                        <div class="label">Bank:</div>
                        <div class="input size50">

 <select name="BankId" class="styled" data-required="true" data-trigger="change">
                    <option value="CORP">CORPORATION </option>
                    <option value="HDFC"> HDFC </option>
                    <option value="ICICI"> ICICI </option>
                    <option value="IDBI"> IDBI </option>
                    <option value="SBI"> STATE BANK OF INDIA </option>
                    <option value="DB"> DEUTSCHE </option>
            </select>


                        </div>
                        <div class="valid"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row name">
                        <div class="label">Amount:</div>
                        <div class="input size50"><input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" data-required="true" placeholder="10.00" data-type="float" data-validation="number"data-validation-allowing="float" data-validation-error-msg="Enter amount as 00.00"/></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" style="float:right" value="Pay Now" class="token_submit" id="btn_process" name="btn_process"/>
            </form>
```

Also the css is

```
* { text-decoration: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; outline: none; box-shadow: none; box-sizing: border-box !important; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box !important; -moz-

box-sizing: border-box !important; -ms-box-sizing: border-box !important; }
    body { font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; color: #263240; padding: 0px; }
    .left { float: left; }
    .right { float: right; }
    .clear { clear: both; }


    a { color: #666; }
    a:hover { color: #333 }

    div#credit-card
    {
        display: table;
        width: 540px;
        margin: 0 auto;

        border: 1px solid #c1c2c8;
        background-color: #eeeeee;
        -moz-border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px 4px;
    }

    div#credit-card > header
    {
        padding: 10px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #c1c2c8;

        background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #dde0e6 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#dde0e6)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#dde0e6 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#dde0e6 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#dde0e6 100%); /* IE10+ */
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%,#dde0e6 100%); /* W3C */
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#dde0e6',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

        -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 3px;
        -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 3px;
        -moz-border-radius-topleft: 3px;
        -moz-border-radius-topright: 3px;
        border-top-left-radius: 3px;
        border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    }

    div#credit-card > header .title
    { 

        color: #666;
        font-size: 13px;
        padding: 15px 0;
            margin-left:10px;
        padding-left: 100px;
        background: no-repeat 20px;

        line-height: 32px;
    }
    div#credit-card > header .close
    {
        display: table;
        float: right;
        margin-right:30px;
        margin-top:4px;

    }

    div#credit-card > header .close:hover
    {
        display: table;
        float: right;
        opacity: 1;
    }

    div#credit-card > header .title strong
    {
        color: #666;
        font-size:12px;
    }

    div#credit-card > section#content
    {
        padding: 30px;
    }

    div#credit-card > section#content .table
    {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
    }

    div#credit-card > section#content .table > .row
    {
        display: table-row;
        width: 100%;
    }   

    div#credit-card > section#content .table > .row > div
    {
        display: table-cell;
        padding-top: 15px;
    }

    div#credit-card > section#content .table > .row > div.label
    {
        min-width: 100px;
        width: 120px;
    }   

    div#credit-card > section#content .form-fields .label
    {
        color: #333;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 12px;
    }   

    div#credit-card > section#content .form-fields .input
    {
        padding-left: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        color: #666;
        font-weight: bold;
        position: relative;
    }       

    div#credit-card > section#content .form-fields .valid
    {
        width: 32px;
        text-align: left;
        padding-left: 10px;

        vertical-align: top;
    }   

    div#credit-card > section#content .form-fields .valid img
    {
        display: block;
        margin-top: 2px;
    }

    div#credit-card > section#content .form-fields .full input, div#credit-card > section#content .form-fields .full select
    {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    div#credit-card > section#content .form-fields input, div#credit-card > section#content .form-fields select
    {
        background-color: #f7f7f7;
        border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
        color: #717171;
        cursor: pointer;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px;border-radius: 5px 5px;

        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        box-shadow: 0 0 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }

    div#credit-card > section#content .form-fields input:hover, div#credit-card > section#content .form-fields select:hover
    {
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        box-shadow: 0 0 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    }

    div#credit-card > section#content .form-fields .size50 input,div#credit-card > section#content .form-fields .size50 select
    {
        display: inline;
        padding-left: 10px;
        width: 40%;
        padding: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px;border-radius: 5px 5px;
    }

    div#credit-card > section#content .form-fields .size50 input:not(:only-child)
    {
        margin-right: 19px;
    }

    div#credit-card > section#content .form-fields .size50 input:last-child
    {
        margin-right: 0;

    }

    div#credit-card > section#content .form-fields .size50 input:only-child
    {
        margin-right: 5px;
    }

    div#credit-card > section#content .form-fields .error
    {
        display: block;
        color: #f34755;
        font-size: 11px;
        margin-top:5px;
        font-weight: normal;
    }

    /* Style Select Boxes */
    span.customStyleSelectBox { -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); box-shadow: 0 0 4px -1px 

rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);cursor: pointer; padding: 8px; background-color: #949494; border: 1px solid #d4d4d4; color: #717171; -moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 

5px;border-radius: 5px 5px; line-height: 11px; width: 100% !important }
    .size50 span.customStyleSelectBox { width: 49% !important; }
    .customStyleSelectBoxInner { padding: 7px 0; background:url(../images/arrow.png) no-repeat center right; width: 100% !important; height: 24px; }

    input[type=submit]
    {
            margin-right:170px;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 12px 40px;
        border: 1px solid #0945b9;
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: 900;
        -moz-border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px 3px;
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 0 -2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 0 -2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
        box-shadow: inset 0 3px 0 -2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        margin-top:20px;


        background: #5e9af8; /* Old browsers */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #5e9af8 0%, #2f6af2 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#5e9af8), color-stop(100%,#2f6af2)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #5e9af8 0%,#2f6af2 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #5e9af8 0%,#2f6af2 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #5e9af8 0%,#2f6af2 100%); /* IE10+ */
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #5e9af8 0%,#2f6af2 100%); /* W3C */
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#5e9af8', endColorstr='#2f6af2',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    }

    input[type=submit]:hover
    {
        background: #2867ef;
    }

    input[type=submit]:active
    {
        background: #2867ef;
    }



input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox] {

        display:none;
    }

input[type=radio] + label, input[type=checkbox] + label {
        display:inline-block;
        margin-left:10px;


        margin-top:5px;
        padding: 4px 25px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 20px;
        color: #ACACAC;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight:bold;
        vertical-align: middle;
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: #ACACAC;
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#e6e6e6);
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,0 0,0 100%,from(#fff),to(#e6e6e6));
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#e6e6e6);
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#e6e6e6);
        background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#fff,#e6e6e6);
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #bfbfbf;
        border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1) rgba(0,0,0,0.1) rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
        border-bottom-color: #b3b3b3;
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff',endColorstr='#ffe6e6e6',GradientType=0);
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    }

     input[type=radio]:checked + label, input[type=checkbox]:checked + label{

    margin-top:5px;
        cursor: pointer;

        border: 1px solid #0945b9;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        -moz-border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px 3px;
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 0 -2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 0 -2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
        box-shadow: inset 0 3px 0 -2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);


        background: #5e9af8; /* Old browsers */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #5e9af8 0%, #2f6af2 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#5e9af8), color-stop(100%,#2f6af2)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #5e9af8 0%,#2f6af2 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #5e9af8 0%,#2f6af2 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #5e9af8 0%,#2f6af2 100%); /* IE10+ */
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #5e9af8 0%,#2f6af2 100%); /* W3C */
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#5e9af8', endColorstr='#2f6af2',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    }

.cards {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.cards li {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  background-image: url('https://www.fethr.com/webapp/images/card_logos.png');
  background-position: 0 0;
  float: left;
  height: 32px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  width: 51px;
}
.cards li:last-child {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.cards .visa_electron {
  background-position: 204px 0;
}
.cards .mastercard {
  background-position: 153px 0;
}
.cards .maestro {
  background-position: 102px 0;
}
.cards .discover {
  background-position: 51px 0;
}
.cards .visa.off {
  background-position: 0 32px;
}
.cards .visa_electron.off {
  background-position: 204px 32px;
}
.cards .mastercard.off {
  background-position: 153px 32px;
}
.cards .maestro.off {
  background-position: 102px 32px;
}
.cards .discover.off {
  background-position: 51px 32px;
}
form input.valid {
  background: url('http://paweldecowski.github.com/jQuery-CreditCardValidator/tick.png') 310px no-repeat;
}
```

Please pardon for the long code here.I have the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/y8UKN/

The fiddle already has a javascript which detects the ccType based on user input.Dont remove it while you cheeck the fiddle.Using that javascript value of ccType is set.if teh set value is 'maestro',cvv should be hiddden

Answer (score 1):

using jQuery

```
$('#ccType').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'maestro')
        $('#cvv').closest('.name').hide(); 
    else
        $('#cvv').closest('.name').show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/y8UKN/1/

I unhid your ccType field but if you type maestro in and then click out of it you will see the cvv dissapear.

So when you click on the different cards if you are changing the value then it should work for you.

**Update**

Here is a more complete example

jQuery

```
$('.cards li').click(function(){
    $('.cards li').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('#ccType').val($(this).html());
    if($('#ccType').val() == 'Maestro')
        $('#cvv').closest('.name').hide(); 
    else
        $('#cvv').closest('.name').show();
});
```

CSS

```
.cards li {
    opacity: .35;
}

.cards .selected {
    opacity: 1;    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y8UKN/3/

Comment: Im afraid ur fiddle is not loading up

Comment: @user3079558 check my update for another example.  It should load for you.. I wonder if the jQuery/javascript is causing an issue loading on your computer.. Try loading it on a different computer etc..

Comment: Yes your code is working perfect.Ya when I add "maestro" inside the field,which were hidden,and when it loose focus,cvv field is hidden.But I add the javascript which automatically fills the hidden field with maestro,but it doesnt hide the cvv..can you check the updated fiddle with your js and the js used for setting the ccType field http://jsfiddle.net/y8UKN/4/

Comment: Something like: `if($(".cards li:not('.off')").length == 1){
            $('#ccType').val($(".cards li:not('.off')").attr('class'));
            if($('#ccType').val() == 'maestro')
                $('#cvv').closest('.name').hide(); 
            else
                $('#cvv').closest('.name').show();           
        }` http://jsfiddle.net/y8UKN/7/